# How to highlight a grid on mouseover in Extjs 4.0?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I want to highlight the whole grid when I move mouse over that grid using some color or maybe by changing border or some other way which should look as if I am selecting the table in **Ext Js 4.0**?

Some other alternative will work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As MarthyM mentions below easier to use 'overCls' instead of listeners. On your grid declaration:

```
overCls: 'borderred'
```

In your style sheet:

```
.borderred { border: 1px solid red; }
```

I've updated the fiddle here using 'overCls' for ExtJS 4.0.7: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/na4

Original answer:

```
 listeners: {
     containermouseover: {
         fn: function (view) {
             view.up('gridpanel').getEl().applyStyles('border: solid 1px red');
         }
     },
     containermouseout: {
         fn: function (view) {
             view.up('gridpanel').getEl().applyStyles('border: solid 1px #99bce8');
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Listeners are working fine but the problem here is it does not work when I move the cursor over the headers or rows of the grid. I need the hover when I move mouse on any part of the grid.

Comment: I have got it. I just replaced "containermouseover" and "containermouseout" with "itemmouseenter" and "itemmouseleave" respectively. Thanks alot. :)

Comment: Great to hear you've got it and thanks for sharing your solution.

Comment: You can simply use `overCls` config. I put in an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to do is set a CSS class using the `overCls` configuration.

```
overCls: 'gridHover'
```

That will add a CSS class to your grid, when a mouse hovers over it. Then you just need to set the style in your CSS:

```
.gridHover {
    border: 2px solid red; /* or any other style */
}
```

And that's it. No need for jQuery or listeners.

Documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-overCls